# RxJS buffer and delay until one other observable emit first time

Tags: rxjs, observable

I'm getting a hard time making a complex observable pipe and I would be grateful if someone could help me on that one…

### Context

I have one stream of data that gives me through Bluetooth some values which are data frames that I have to decode.

This is a BehaviorSubject called `RX$`.

Now on `RX$`, sometimes I receive Instant Data (INST) and sometimes History Data (HIST). With INST, I receive besides other things the device that is sending data version and model. I successfully generated an observable that is able to compute me a JSON object with the device version and model and that don't emit as long as it don't have both, let's call it `deviceVersionModelStream$`

Now on the other side, I receive HIST data frames in bulk in a stream we will call `historyStream$`, and because there is a lot of data, I used `bufferTime(2000)` to make an array of data and rely on my embedded database bulk insert (instead of one by one).

This worked well until now…

### New use case

Now my customer added a new rule, they have an old device type that is not able to give me some data for a specific case, but using the same pattern I know what else it is giving to me.

Therefore, I need to have the device version and model before decoding frame and insert in the database.

My question is, how can I delay `historyStream$` occurrences as long as `deviceVersionModelStream$` emit one time (it's a HOT one too used on others places) and when it occurs, I want to generate some kind of JSON object with both the raw frame and the version/model.

But ALSO gradually dispatch this information to not overwhelm my database bulk inserts, as my bufferTime(2000) did before?.

I'm trying things with buffer, mergeMap, delay, but I'm having hard time achieving this one…

Maybe someone strong with RX could help me?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

This post is a little old, but I recently stumbled upon it while looking for a "buffer rxjs observables until another event occurred", and I thought I would share what an updated version would look like.

I built this on https://thinkrx.io. Here is the code I used:

```js
const { rxObserver } = require('api/v0.3');
const { timer, of, combineLatest, concat } = require('rxjs');
const { delay, take, share, buffer, mergeAll, bufferTime, filter, takeUntil, skipUntil } = require('rxjs/operators');



const historyStream$ = timer(0, 10).pipe(
  share(), take(10)
);

const versionModel$ = of("A").pipe(
  delay(50), 
  take(1)
);

historyStream$.subscribe(rxObserver('History Stream'));
versionModel$.subscribe(rxObserver('Version Model'));

combineLatest([
  versionModel$,
  concat([
    historyStream$.pipe(buffer(versionModel$)),
    historyStream$.pipe(skipUntil(versionModel$))
  ]).pipe(
    mergeAll()
  )]
).subscribe(rxObserver("Buffer Window"));
```

Here is the output:

[image: Marble diagram of solution]

What's going on here is that we are passing two observables into `concat`: one that represents the buffered set of events, and on that represents the stream of events as they come in. We finally pipe all of that into `mergeAll` to get the appropriate effect.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, always nice for science ;)

Answer (score 2):

#### 1 General Idea - switching back and forth between buffered and unbuffered

Looks like you need to pause (buffer) `historyStream$` in the beginning and then unpause it when `deviceVersionModelStream$` emits. A way to pause/unpause streams is.

```ts
merge(
  source$.pipe(bufferToggle(pauseOn$, () => pauseOff$)),
  source$.pipe(windowToggle(pauseOff$, () => pauseOn$))
).pipe(mergeAll())
```

Also see: https://medium.com/@kddsky/pauseable-observables-in-rxjs-58ce2b8c7dfd

#### Your specific case

For your case this would be:

```ts
const versionModel$ = deviceVersionModelStream$.pipe(take(1));
merge(
  historyStream$.pipe(bufferToggle(of(0), v => versionModel$)),
  historyStream$.pipe(windowToggle(versionModel$, v => NEVER))
).pipe(
  mergeAll(),
  bufferTime(2000)
);
```

If you want to have the output of `deviceVersionModelStream$` accessible on every emit you could use `combineLatest`. If multiple subscriptions to `historyStream$` and `deviceVersionModelStream$` are a problem you can use [`share`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/share) beforehand.

```ts
const versionModel$ = deviceVersionModelStream$.pipe(share(), take(1));
const historyStreamShared$ = historyStream$.pipe(share());
combineLatest(
  versionModel$,
  merge(
    historyStreamShared$.pipe(bufferToggle(of(0), v => versionModel$)),
    historyStreamShared$.pipe(windowToggle(versionModel$, v => NEVER))
  ).pipe(
    mergeAll(),
    bufferTime(2000)
  )
).subscribe(console.log);
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-oyctsg

**Edit (if you only need the buffer once at the beginning)**

In your case you don't need to be able to use the buffer again once it's turned off, i.e. once you switch from the bufferToggle to the windowToggle stream you won't need to switch back to the bufferToggle stream.

This allows for a slightly simple approach using only `buffer` instead of `bufferToggle` and `windowToggle`.

#### 2 General Idea - buffer only at the beginning

```ts
source$ = dataStream.pipe(share()) // make sure this is a hot observable
pauseOff$ = timer(5000) // make sure this observable emits once and completes

concat(
  source$.pipe(buffer(pauseOff$), mergeAll()), // start with a buffered stream
  source$ // switch to the unbuffered stream when pauseOff$ emits and completes the previous stream
)
```

#### Your specific case

```ts
const historyStream$ = timer(0, 100).pipe(share(), take(200));
const versionModel$ = of("version-model").pipe(delay(5000), take(1));

combineLatest(
  versionModel$,
  concat(
    historyStream$.pipe(buffer(versionModel$), mergeAll()),
    historyStream$
  ).pipe(
    bufferTime(2000)
  )
).subscribe(console.log);
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-2ptrux

Comment: Woooah, okay… Ima try this one, but I don't really get the use of windowToggle?

Do you have an article of something about the pause/unpause stream combination ?

Comment: `bufferToggle` just buffers values between `pauseOn$` -> `pauseOff$` and emits those values on `pauseOff$`. Values that arrive at other times are omitted. That's why you need a second stream with `windowToggle` to emit values between `pauseOff$` -> `pauseOn$`.